# How do I set firefox non-gmail webmail as the windows 10 system MAPI client

Tags: windows-10, firefox, email, webmail

I would like to set the Windows 10 MAPI client to firefox, such that it opens my preferred webmail to send a new message. This is not technically difficult, however...

This is surprisingly hard to search for on the internet. No, dear hyper-optimized search results for the common case, I do NOT want

- to set the mail client in the browser for mailto: links on web pages (I already set that).
- to set the *outgoing* mail client in firefox (ironic)
- to set the MAPI client to an installed program other than firefox, eg a mail client; I want to set it to firefox.
- to set Thunderbird as the MAPI client; yes you are oh so clever to understand that firefox and thunderbird are both made by mozilla; but I typed exactly what I want: firefox, not thunderbird.
- to set the default Windows Mail client as my MAPI client (I typed firefox)
- to set Outlook as the MAPI client (I typed firefox)
- to set the default mail program in Windows 10 settings (altho, if that worked, I would be happy)
- to set the MAPI client to Chrome (I typed firefox)
- to set the MAPI client to gmail (I said "webmail", nothing about gmail)
- to set the Windows 'Sent To' link in Windows shell

(The era of being able to search for specific things appears to be over. The search engines seem to rank popular answers higher than matches to your specific search terms. I assume that so many people provide sloppy search terms, perhaps because they don't know exactly what they're searching for, that the search engines *assume* that you don't know what you're searching for. Admittedly, that is me often. However, if you do know exactly what you're searching for, God help you. Get a time machine and back to 1990, or get $1 billion and make your own google.)

The way I imagine this MAPI-firefox working is, I am in some program (Windows file explorer, Windows photo viewer, Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, or many others) and I click that program's "send to email recipient" or similar.

That program calls out to Windows 10 to invoke whatever MAPI client is set and requests a new message.

That MAPI client is firefox.

Firefox receives the request for a new message, and consults its mailto: link settings and picks the default to invoke that webmail link (with its parameters) to start a new webmail message.

If firefox can't do that (but why not? doesn't seem hard) then a 3rd party program that receives the MAPI request and opens the firefox mail:to link seems easy to write.

If it doesn't exist, maybe I ought to write one.

But I can't be the first person who wants this. It would have to already exist.

**EDIT**: In response to comment, my specific application is in LibreOffice `File - Send - Document as E-mail.` But of course, any internet wanderer might land here needing a solution for any random application which uses any part of the MAPI interface.

- [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1440/how-can-i-send-documents-through-email-from-libreoffice/) in 2012 someone reported that LibreOffice uses MAPI.
- and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936528/setting-gmail-as-default-for-sending-files-via-email) in 2017 someone considered a *linux* application (I need windows) called `desktop-webmail` which I am guessing interfaces with MAPI then calls webmail via a browser.

**EDIT 2**: In response to reading [closed for asking for software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software), it suggests:

- "Do your research" : I read the first 1000 answers on google (well, DuckDuckGo, then Bing, then Google when I couldn't find anything, 1000 estimated in total). That's how I generated my list of all the answers that *aren't* my answer.
- "ask about your problem instead" : In the opening of my post I describe the exact technical problem I need a solution to. Because I've "done my research" I know that this problem is often, perhaps only, solved by a piece of software, so later I go on to ask if that may be a solution.
- This *question* is common in search engines. The *answer* is not. That's what I think *this* site is good for.

**EDIT 3**: Also, in response to comment, (while researching the `MAILTO` protocol, which appears to handle `mailto:` URL links, which is not the same as MAPI) I came across [this description](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/set-edge-as-mailto-default-handler/m-p/1487878/highlight/true#M32213) from 2020 of a similar option in *google chrome + gmail* (in a question about *Edge*  (which is now based on chromium)):

> - Toggle the “Allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols (recommended)” to On in Settings.
> - Sign in to your Gmail account.
> - Click the handler icon in the address bar. It's on the right side, by the star. It looks like two overlapped diamonds. When you hover over it with the mouse, the pop up says “This page wants to install a service handler”.
> - A pop up box will appear that says “Allow mail.google.com to open all email links?” choose Allow.

Is there an equivalent for Firefox?

Comment: Could you describe which features of MAPI you need? Are the features available in the `mailto` protocol enough for you or do you need MAPI things such as attachments?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question. Short answer: LibreOffice Send Document as E-mail.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible out of the box. You could use a commercial solution such as Affixa or MAPI4Webmail, but both seem a bit shady to me. You could implement your own MAPI handler to get the job done, but not sure you are desparate enough. See for instance http://jankeirse.github.io/tvhgooglemapi/ to get you started.

Comment: You don't need to specify an edit with "edit", the revision history, handles changes to a contribution.  Fix the formating of this question and I may vote to reopen.